# WCF service Hosting Servers

Tags: wcf

I created the service using WCF. As i know i can host in IIS.

Is it possible to host WCF all servers (like apache).?

Please provide the list of server where can host the WCF service and where its best to host service?

Answer (score 2):

You can host your WCF services:

- in IIS/WAS (preferably IIS 7.x or newer); IIS 5.1 and IIS 6.0 only support HTTP bindings, while IIS 7.x through WAS supports *all* WCF bindings
- or you can self-host in any managed application (NT Service, console app, WPF app - whatever); supports *all* WCF bindings and gives you the ultimate control over how your services are hosted / available

Those are your options.

Read:

- [MSDN : Hosting WCF Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730158.aspx) - with further links to hosting in IIS, WAS and self-hosting

Comment: My question,  is it possible to host in Apache also? as i know web pages (.asmx)  can host in apache. but WCF service not able to host. Will you provide  Mod_mono steps to host WCF service

Comment: @Mahantesh: I don't know whether Mod_mono will support that, sorry. If you have a Mono managed application, you should be able to host a WCF service - but I'm not sure about Apache/Mod_mono